# How to left align, number the items in a gantt chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I want to create a Gantt Chart in latex and I want to aligned the items in the Gantt Chart to the left and to use numbering and sub numbering as well. But, I've not come across such a thing before. It'd be a grate help if anyone could help on this.

Comment: Could you show us a draft of what you have in mind? Also see [this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf) document, it may help

Comment: 06. Implementation of Infrastructure- full time span, Under Infrastructure; 6.1. Roads - time taken for the roads, 6.2. Water - time taken for the water, 6.3. Electricity etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of guesswork, and no sub-numbering (whatever exactly you mean by that), but here is a quick example, there are a few explanatory comments in the code, ask if anything is entirely unclear.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} % for ganttcharts
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \AtBeginEnvironment

% make a new counter for the line number in a chart
\newcounter{ganttline}
% set the counter to zero at start of every ganttchart environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{ganttchart}{\setcounter{ganttline}{0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  % for each of bar, group, milestone:
  %   - step the line counter
  %   - print the current value of the counter followed by period
  %   - add text of item in the default manner at the end
  bar label text={\refstepcounter{ganttline}\arabic{ganttline}. \strut#1},
  group label text={\refstepcounter{ganttline}\arabic{ganttline}. \strut#1},
  milestone label text={\refstepcounter{ganttline}\arabic{ganttline}. \strut#1},
  % set text in a 5cm wide box, adjust 5cm to your liking
  bar label node/.append style={text width=5cm},
  group label node/.append style={text width=5cm},
  milestone label node/.append style={text width=5cm}
]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

With some lines:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} % for ganttcharts
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \AtBeginEnvironment

% make a new counter for the line number in a chart
\newcounter{ganttline}
% set the counter to zero at start of every ganttchart environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{ganttchart}{\setcounter{ganttline}{0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  % for each of bar, group, milestone:
  %   - step the line counter
  %   - print the current value of the counter followed by period
  %   - add text of item in the default manner at the end
  bar label text={\refstepcounter{ganttline}\arabic{ganttline}. \strut#1},
  group label text={\refstepcounter{ganttline}\arabic{ganttline}. \strut#1},
  milestone label text={\refstepcounter{ganttline}\arabic{ganttline}. \strut#1},
  % set text in a 5cm wide box, adjust 5cm to your liking
  % give the node a name that depends on the counter
  % the counter is stepped after the naming, so label0 is the first, label4 is the last
  bar label node/.append style={text width=5cm,name=label\arabic{ganttline}},
  group label node/.append style={text width=5cm,name=label\arabic{ganttline}},
  milestone label node/.append style={text width=5cm,name=label\arabic{ganttline}},
  % the canvas node makes the frame around the chart
  canvas/.append style={name=canvas},
]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}

% draw a vertical line relative to the top left corner of label0 and bottom left corner of label4
\draw ([xshift=1.3em]label0.north west) -- ([xshift=1.3em]label4.south west);

% draw horizontal lines between the nodes
\foreach [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1)}] \x in {0,...,3}
 {
   % define helper coordinate halfway between the left corners
   \path (label\x.south west) -- coordinate (m\x) (label\y.north west);
   % draw a line from that coordinate to the canvas box
   \draw (m\x) -- (m\x -| canvas.west);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot sir

Comment: Sir, I want to learn a little thing. I want to separate the items and numbers with horizontal and vertical lines. only if you'd have enough time, could you help on this and is there any learning materials on packages frequently used?

Comment: @DAPadme See updated code. Most packages has a manual, which you can access by opening a command prompt/terminal on your computer and entering `texdoc <name of package>`, for example `texdoc pgfgantt`. Alternatively go to http://texdoc.net/ to access documentation. For this case, in addition to the `pgfgantt` manual, the manual for TikZ/`pgf` is relevant. That manual is very extensive, but start by studying the tutorials in chapters 2-6.